# Files folder not showing in heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, server

My folders

[image]

and my gitignore file
[image]

but my assets folder "data" is not uploading to heroku.
this is my ls in heroku console.

[image]

Why it is not uploading my asset folder. Also i don't want to upload my assets so I used neglected every pdf or image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your folder contains only files which are ignored by your `.gitignore`. Empty folders are not automatically uploaded to github or heroku unless they contain "something." Try adding a simple `.txt` file, commit that change, and see if it works.